# Cannot access server using its ip address

Tags: apache, centos

I have web server, I can use it with ssh connection, `ssh root@ip`

But I can't access it as web server. I tested simply python tool, http.server and also tested installing and starting `httpd`.

Output for:

```
# ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2 }'
addr:[ip address that I'm using for ssh]
addr:
```

OS: Centos

What else I must do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with firewall. Solved using this instruction: [Configure iptables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-a-basic-ip-tables-configuration-on-centos-6)